# Ansi-C 89 - Copy two .txt's, fgetc not working some how

Tags: c, c89

I am preparing for my CS exam in procedural programming and my code doesn't work.

**The task:** Using command line arguments for the path, copy the contents of one text file into another.

**Example with** `cmd.exe: myCodeCompiled.exe Original.txt Copy.txt`.

**My call was (also caused the error):**

```
"C:\\Users\\jonny\\Desktop\\bin\\Debug\\Blatt9.exe"
"C:\\Users\\jonny\\Desktop\\bin\\Debug\\copy.txt" 
"C:\\Users\\jonny\\Desktop\\bin\\Debug\\original.txt"
```

**NOTE: My call was added after the solution was found. It caused the error.**

As usual, there isn't much to say except no giving length for the content or "Original.txt", such that `EOF` is used to check (just for example).

**My idea:** `fgetc(Original.txt) != EOF` => `fputc(Copy.txt)`

Both files already existing.

My function gets the `argv` passed as a parameter.
The calling function (in this case the `main()`) is checking for `argc == 3`.

**My code:**

```
void copy(char *argv[]) {
   //considering that argv[1] and argv[2] are valid char-arrays
    FILE *org = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *kop = fopen(argv[2], "a");
        //changed to int, before it was unsigned int, then char and now its a int
    int c = 0; //got the dec out of for-loop
    if (org == NULL || kop == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR");
        return;
    }
    for (c = fgetc(org); c != EOF; c = fgetc(org)) {
        fputc(c, kop);
    }
    fclose(org);   OLD CODE
    fclose(kop);*/
    //new code for more information.
    //print("%d", fclose(org)); //prints -1 on error, 0 on success
    //print("%d", fclose(kop));
}
```

I really appreciate any help, and I have no clue why its not working.

**Edit, PS: Additional information:**

**Copy.txt** and **Original.txt** aren't changed afterwards. I also had a `printf("\n");` above the `fputc`; no single line was printed.

**The includes/defines and the `main()` which are in this file.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define print printf
#define NEWLINE printf("\n")
#define N 21
#define BN 23
#define SKIP 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //code that has no influence since its just struct implementation and transformation
    if (argc == 3) {
        printf("\nstring the copying...\n");
        copy(argv);
    } else
        printf("ERROR_ the argc is not mathing 3"); //added
    return 0;
}
```

**-------------- EDIT --------------**
Thanks for all the answer, many lines had failurs

***change-log:***

- added else to the argc check
- added printf to the fclose, this will show -1 incase of error (now as comments, such that no ansi violation is caused by that)
  (probably not ansi but nice to have right now)
- **changed/added declation out of the for-loop (thats ansi)**
- Added main and all includes/define, making sure its not causing the failur.

***Solution***
Well, big thanks to everyone who help, you guys are awesome and quick like fox.

**What caused the problem?**

Stupid me, I really should have mentioned how my command prommt looked like. I dont deserve you guys.

Anyways, this was my prompt input ( I used `\\` twice except for the calling `.exe`. Also used with single `\\` and `""` with and without the `\\`.
Changed it to literally just copy.txt and original.txt.

```
> "C:\\Users\\jonny\\Desktop\\bin\\Debug\\Blatt9.exe"
> "C:\\Users\\jonny\\Desktop\\bin\\Debug\\copy.txt" 
> "C:\\Users\\jonny\\Desktop\\bin\\Debug\\original.txt"
```

**This fixed my problem tough**

```
"C:\Users\jonny\Desktop\\bin\Debug\Blatt9.exe" original.txt copy.txt
```

And of course it makes sense, I have to understand the \role alot more, but since the double \ in a `const *char` worked, I thought I could with `*argv[]` too...

Sorry again for the trouble and thank you very much!

Comment: Where did you get the idea of using an `unsigned int c` in that loop? What do you expect `EOF` to be?

Comment: @Gerhardh Unusual, but shouldn't be an issue since comparing for inequality...

Comment: The internet, thought it would make sense since a char is a unsigned int.

It didnt changed the results for me.

Comment: @RetoZ `char` being signed or unsigned is *implementation defined* – that's why for fully portable code you need to explicitly cast to `unsigned char` if using `isalpha`, `isdigit`, ... functions.

Comment: @Gerhardh I know right? My university wants me to program on paper too, but thats another topic and misery

I would rather use the texteditor

Comment: nice to know, I also like the smooth rime of yours :D  
@Aconcagua

I tried to cast everything into unsigned and signed, didnt changed it in this scenario, but I definitly take a note on that!

Comment: @Jong UN / 0____________

I really dont know, but fgetc can be found in here : https://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/ansic-library.html, it should be ansi but idk if its even ansi 89 \\_[._.]_/

Comment: In your question, you state that both files exist. However, you do not state whether the source file is empty or not. An empty source file would explain the behavior described in your question.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel copy.txt is empty and the original file has basic letters and three \n init (but not written as "\n").

Also single lined is not working

Comment: The part that is not ANSI C89 is the definition of a variable inside the head of the `for` loop. In C89 you must define the variable before the loop, at the top of current block.

Comment: @Gerhardh I did changed it now, I gotta get used to it.

Comment: @0___________ stupid me again... Sorry, you are right! I changed it again.

Comment: As I have written above, in C89 all variable definitions must go to the top of your current block. Defining `int c` after an `if` statement is invalid. Run it in a compiler where you select `C89` standard if you are unsure.

Comment: The reason why you should use `int` instead of `char` or `unsigned int` is because the value that `fgetc` is returning is of type `int`. It does this because is the returned value must be able to represent every possible character code (`0`-`255` on most platforms) as well as the special macro constant `EOF`, which is usually defined as `-1`. The data types `char` and `unsigned int` are unable to do this, on most platforms.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yup, my bad. Thank you for the clear explanation. I will considere this since I undertsand it now :D

Comment: @Gerhardh You are right, I changed that now, hopefully never do such a failur in the examine :[]

Comment: @0___________ AndreasWenzel Gerhardh Thank you to you all, you helped not only with my problem, with which Iam struggling for too long, but also teaching and hinting me to check the ansi, believe it or not but this is VERY important since its for the examine and you probably saved my a*s :D

You guys are awesome, and sorry if you took your time even if it wasnt maybe not worth it. 
0___________  Iam also looking forward to use more error handleing in my code, such that I code with more acuracy!

Comment: Don't `printf()` the `fclose()`, check the return like you are supposed to `if (fclose(kop)) { perror ("fclose-kop"); }` You only need to check the *Close-After-Write* to catch errors that wouldn't be caught checking the return of `fputc()` (stream errors, errors flushing bytes to file, etc..) No need to check the return of `fclose(org);`, nothing changed and you would catch the read-error with `fgetc()`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity – why does it have to be C89 at all? With more than 30 years of age that appears superseded to me in pretty much every respect I can think of (apart from discovering some really old hardware where a compiler supporting a more recent standard simply is not available...).

Comment: `if (org == NULL || kop == NULL) { return; }` (actually I'd rather prefer `if(!org || !kop)`) would leave one file unclosed if just a single one could be opened... I personally prefer `org = open(); if (org) { cop = open(); if(cop) { /*...*/ close(cop); } close(org); }` or with error messages `if(!(org = open()) { /* error */ } else { ... }`. To avoid too deep nesting you then might pass both pointers to a separate function doing the actual work.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel To be precise: While correct about the/any char type `unsigned int` very well *can* hold any value of the available output range – just that the negative values are converted to (large) positive ones, but these still are uniquely identifyable – *and* compare correctly to the `EOF` constant, which, as of type int, is promoted to unsigned, too, because of same size. So `unsigned int` indeed is not fully correct, sure, but won't produce any problem *in given case* (matter would change on comparing e.g. `< 0`, of course!).